# How to safely return hash tokens or sensitive data in unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, testing, token

I've got some password reset functionality that I'm re-writing but adding tests.

My test should:

1. Create a user entry in the DB
2. Create a hash token entry in the DB for that user
3. Verify that the hash token matches an entry in the DB.

The last one (3), I'm having trouble testing, because typically, I wouldn't return the hash token to the user (client) in production. Instead, I'd fire off an event to my taskworker with the hash token string being passed around in memory and then send them an email with the secret link.

My route for verification looks like:

`server.get('/api/v1/users/password/reset/:token', userPasswordReset.fetch)`

Such that, as you can see, I need to grab `token` from the request parameter, which means I need to have it sent back to me somehow (but only in a test environment, NOT in production).

To currently solve for this, in my controller I'm currently doing this:

```
      return process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test'
        ? res.status(201).send({ token: record.token })
        : res.status(201).end()
```

However, I'd like to know if there is a safer way to go about this. I don't love the idea of putting fragile code in my production code that is dependent upon an env variable.

I've thought about writing the token to a file on the system, but because these tests will run within different environments I'm not sure that's entirely reliable based upon virtual filesystems.

Answer (score 0):

You should only be testing your public API. You don't test a scenario that is invalid. You can test hash creation and storage of token at DB layer. Hope this helps.

Comment: I need to ensure that going to that link for the user will update their status to confirmed (which is in another table). That route I posted above, is actually part of my public API.